Kommasetzung in "Er war daran beteiligt, oder nicht?"
ich habe eine Frage zur Kommasetzung in folgendem Satz:

„Er war daran beteiligt, oder nicht?”

Ist das Komma hier korrekt gesetzt? Nach meinem Ermessen ja, da es sich um eine Abtrennung einer Frage handelt. Jedoch bin ich mir nicht ganz sicher und wollte eure Meinung dazu hören.

Vorsicht mit Fragen nach Meinungen! Wenn ich glauben würde, dass du wirklich an persönlichen Meinungen anderer Menschen interessiert wärst, müsste ich dafür stimmen, deine Frage mit der Begründung "opinion-based" zu schließen. Fragen nach subjektiven Meinungen von Einzelpersonen sind ausdrücklich unerwünscht auf allen Ablegern von Stackexchange. Erwünscht sind hingegen Fragen danach, ob ...

... etwas richtig oder falsch ist, also Fragen nach objektiv nachprüfbaren Fakten. Da ich glaube, dass du in Wahrheit wissen willst, was richtig und was falsch ist, werde ich nicht für das Schließen deiner Frage stimmen. Aber zur Sicherheit solltest du deine Frage bitte editieren und so formulieren, dass das auch klar wird. (Du willst keine Diskussion mit Meinungsaustausch anzetteln, sondern du bist an einer faktisch korrekten Antwort interessiert.)

Es ist normaler Sprachgebrauch das Wort Meinung im weitesten Sinne zu nutzen. Es geht hier um eine Aussage über eine Tatsache, die im Kern wahr oder falsch sein kein, wenn es eine Regel dazu gibt, aber wenn man nicht sicher ist, ob die Regel so stimmt, sagt man "Ich meine, ...". Ich sehe hier keine Ermunterung diffuse Stimmungen und persönlichen Vorlieben zu diskutieren.

Zunächst mal zur Frage selbst:

Ist das Komma hier korrekt gesetzt?

Die Antwort ist: das kommt darauf an. Es kommt darauf an, was genau Du ausdrücken willst.
Die erste Möglichkeit ist, daß Du zwei mögliche Alternativen aufzählen möchtest, nämlich, erstens, daß er beteiligt war oder daß, zweitens, er nicht beteiligt war. Das wäre die Kurzform von:

Er war daran beteiligt oder er war nicht daran beteiligt.

In dem Fall wird kein Komma zwischen den beiden Hauptsätzen gesetzt, weil das "oder" dessen Funktion schon erfüllt (genauso, wie das auch "und" tun würde). Allerdings wäre das eine Feststellung und deshalb das Fragezeichen falsch. Dann müßte da stattdessen ein Punkt hin.
Soweit die erste Möglichkeit. Die zweite Lesart wäre, daß das "oder nicht" nur als Floskel angehängt wird und etwa gleichbedeutend mit formelhaften Wendungen wie "nicht wahr" verwendet wird. Auf Englisch etwa wäre das dann nicht mehr:

He took part or he didn't. (erste Variante)

sondern

He took part, didn't he? (zweite Variante)

Das "oder" verliert in solchen formelhaften Wendungen seine Funktion als Konjunktion und deshalb wird ein Komma gesetzt.
